# Airpods seem to have a Chinese name by default

Tags: airpods

When I set up a pair of airpods, the name shown is in what appears to be Chinese + English:

[image: speaker selection]

This isn't a big deal, but I'm wondering why it does this. What do those Chinese characters mean?

Comment: That's the name of the AirPods.  Did you buy them new or refurb?

Comment: Bought them new from apple's site

Comment: When you set them up did you give them this name?

Comment: No, I don't think it asked for one. But if it did I didn't notice it

Comment: You might've supplied a name with characters iOS thought were Chinese, I'm not sure.  If you think they might be refurb, you can take them back and replace them.  Otherwise, just rename them.

Comment: Hmm they seem new to me but not sure why I see that name

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't see that name if they're new.  If it was me, I'd return them for a replacement but it's up to you.  I've never heard nor seen that happen with new AirPods.

Comment: They're (supposed to be) the updated model so maybe it's a new bug they introduced?

Comment: Could be but I've not seen anything on the internet about it.

Comment: In case anybody is wondering, "木风的" seems to mean "woody" (I hope I got the Chinese characters right...), according to Google Translate (https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=木风的)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my name is Mei, and to answer first character 枫 ( fēng ) is a component to a chinese name and literally means "Maple" and second character 的 ( de ) is a possessive particle or meaning "of" or belonging to, to put simply it means "Feng's AirPods"

Comment: Wow thanks for that. Did I get ripped off paying full price for these I wonder...

Comment: Quite possibly, or may have got mixed up when selecting a pair to send, i would see if possible you can get them exchanged, or if they are working fine and you have no problem with the way they are you can always rename them, hope this was helpful

Comment: Thanks. If I do keep them I'm not renaming them I'll just be Feng

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, and if it is annoying you, I would suggest just [running a factory reset](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/factory-reset-apple-airpods-may-help-battery-pairing-issues/) on the AirPods. It might help :)

From [The Mac Observer](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/factory-reset-apple-airpods-may-help-battery-pairing-issues/):

> ## How to Factory Reset Apple AirPods, May Help with Battery and Pairing Issues
>
> - Put your AirPods in their case—keep the lid open.
>
> [image: The Mac Observer - AirPods photo]
>
> 1. Hold the button on the back, as shown above, for three to five seconds until the amber light blinks three times.
> 2. Close the lid.
> 3. On your iPhone, go to Settings > Bluetooth > AirPods and Forget This Device, as shown below